# Expired SSL Certificate and Encryption

Tags: security, encryption, ssl, certificate

I am relatively new to the world of web development and wanted to know if an expired SSL certificate renders encryption useless or does the site remain encrypted however not tell the user that there is a valid certificate that has not expired?

Comment: SSL doesn't encrypt the site, just the transmissions to/from the site, I thought.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly the same situation with a self-signed certificate. The connection will still be encrypted but the browser will warn the user of 'untrusted' certificate (either expired or self-signed).

Actually SSL certificate does not encrypt the contents of the web page. It is encrypted with AES (or a compatible symmetric encryption available to the user's browser). Your SSL certificate is used for key agreement for the symmetric encryption.

Definitelly skim through some "[Transport Layer Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)" articles.

Comment: @Teoman Soygul - Thanks. So when you say **It is encrypted with AES** are you referring to the actual content? Also when you say the that **the connection will be encrypted**, how is this different to the content being encrypted?

Comment: The content is encrypted with AES (the HTML). When I say connection, I refer to the handshake procedure where the password for AES encryption is decided between the two parties. That password is encrypted with your SSL certificate's public key (actually not exactly but, simplifying). Public key encryption is very costly in terms of computational power so only AES password is encrypted with the cert's public key. Rest is handled by AES which eats up a lot less computer ticks to encrypt the content.

Comment: @Teoman Soygul - So even if the SSL certificate has expired, the connection would still be encrypted. Now assuming I was accessing my email account via webmail that utilizes SSL and that SSL certificate has expired, the connection would be encrypted as would the contents with AES. Is that right? So the only real 'issue' is of trust.

Comment: Yes and yes. Expired or not, your connection is fully encrypted. As you say, the only issue is trust (and Firefox's ugly warnings about expired certificates). Especially in smaller corporations, securing webmail through self-signed (thus untrusted) certificates is a common practice. It still provides the encrypted connection and prevents ears-dropping.

Comment: 'Your SSL certificate is used for key agreement for the symmetric encryption.'. No it isn't. It is used to establish an authentic identity. Only.

Comment: Actually you're right on that. Two parties generate two unique sets or RSA keys and exchange public keys and then use them for key agreement for the symmetric encryption. Sorry, I was just trying to simplify.

Comment: Most browsers today refuse to connect and will bring up UI notifying the user of the problem. Some then allow you to click some buttons to ignore it while others do not. In any event, HTTPS means it's either encrypted or no data is sent at all.

Comment: "Actually SSL certificate does not encrypt the contents of the web page. It is encrypted with AES" 
I think would have been read better this way:

"Actually RSA does not encrypt the contents of the web page. It is encrypted with AES"